# How to use MVC to save form's (view) data that belongs to two different tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, razor

I'm an experienced Java Developer working with a web-application project built using  MVC/C#/Razor.  I need to modify the project so that it retrieves data from two separate tables; there are 2 columns that no longer belong to `table1` (and its pertaining Model) but now need to be saved to the new `table2` once the form is submitted.

I still don't quite get the MVC separation.  Does Models are exact table representations, form representations or both.  And if they can be both how do I "distribute" a form's data across the tables that are in charge of saving it.

Sorry if I'm not clear but I'm very new to Razor, C#, ASP.NET and MS's MVC.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: View models do not represent data entities. As their name implies, they model your view. Combine everything you need in your view in a view model and populate it with the appropriate data.

Answer (score 1):

İf i did not get you wrong , you want to combine tables in 1 model and return 1 model.

You can create a custom model representing the data needed for your view.

```
public class UserView
{
public User User{get;set;}
public List<Messages> Messages{get;set;}
}
```

And then,

```
return View(new UserView(){ User = user, Messages = message});
```

In the view:

```
Model.User;
Model.Messages;
```

Hope shows you a way to solve your problem.

Comment: It was quite helpful. Thanks!